# How to pass string variable from dart to php file

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I'm trying to send string variable to php file with post method this is my function in dart:

```
 Future<Verify> verifyOTP() async {
    var response_verifyotp = await http.post(Uri.parse(linkverifyOTP), body: {
      "OTP_code": SOTP,
    });

    if (response_verifyotp.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response_verifyotp.body);
      st_verfiy = Verify.fromJson(json.decode(response_verifyotp.body));
      print(st_verfiy.status);
    }
  }
```

but it doesn't pass correctly still appear to me it's missing value

I'm try also with:  "OTP_code": SOTP.toString(),
it's same

This is my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$ch = curl_init();
$OTP_code=$_POST["OTP_code"];
if(isset($_SESSION["id"]))
$id=$_SESSION["id"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.msegat.com/gw/verifyOTPCode.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);


$fields = <<<EOT
{
   "lang":"EN",
  "userName": "Bloom_Ducks",
  "apiKey":"f92b62af08ed0be",
  "code":"$OTP_code",
  "id": "$id" ,
  "userSender":"APP"
}
EOT;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json"
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response=json_decode($response,true);
$code=$response["code"];

   if($code == 1){
         json_encode(array("status" => 1));
    }else{
        json_encode(array("status" => 0));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Both your Dart code and your PHP code appearing to be making HTTP requests, which is the "client" and which is the "server"?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm not sure if I answer your question correctly but I'm send request to provider service which is msegat and my php file I uploaded in our server which is Domainracer trying to connect the service OTP with login interface in flutter project.

Comment: If your problem is getting data from Dart to PHP, then what you do with that data after successfully receiving it is another problem. If this is the case, then we don't need to be concerned with any of the `curl` code. If the problem is with the PHP API request using the supplied code, then we don't need any of the Dart code. I'm just trying to simplify and focus the code so no one is distracted by things that aren't relevant to the problem.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I want to take the code which user entered in the interface and send it to php to send request of verification to provider and return 1 for success or 0 then return the status to interface either to login the user successfully or not

Comment: You want to do _abc_, and then you want to do _xyz_. One has to happen before the other. If both aren't working, it is because the first isn't working. Whatever you are doing in the second thing is not related to the problem. Please try to simplify this down to the smallest amount of code that relates to your problem.

Comment: @ChrisHaas my problem is here (body: {
      "OTP_code": SOTP,) because SOTP is a string variable and not pass to php correctly and when I try to change to var and use SOTP.text, there is error appear to me